# The image is not resizing right

Tags: css

A friend using the Tor Browser says that for him the image resizing is not right. Inspecting can not find the error. For me is ok.
The site use skeleton.css http://euphonia.com.br/

Pic: http://euphonia.com.br/?attachment_id=80

As I do not like to leave this bug, does anyone know how to fix? Thanks for the attention

Comment: @Sprottenwels From what I gather the issue is that when viewed over the Tor network the site looks different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have a floated image with no constraints, so it can overflow freely and will give you unexpected results at different resolutions IF AND ONLY IF Tor does not allow for media queries...which by the judging the project is having difficulties with.  Try a simple google for "Tor media queries" and read up.

I suggest either: revamping the entire site away from a responsive design or: tell the Tor people they need to deal with it.  What is the potential Tor-driven traffic for your blog? 1? 2 people?  Probably not enough to fret over.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why this might not be working. The first, and most basic could simply be that your friend is using a different browser (Firefox with Tor I think) so the CSS is rendering differently.

After viewing using Chrome, running Tor there is no issue with it so that may be your issue.